# How would I get the corresponding Key for the maximum Value in a Dictionary(Of SomeEnum, Integer) using LINQ?

Tags: vb.net, linq, dictionary

I did a fair bit of searching for an answer to this question, but no example that I could find got all the way to where I need to be.

I've got a `Dictionary(Of SomeEnum, Integer)` that gets filled up while looping through some objects that have a property with type `SomeEnum`. Once the loop is done, I want the `SomeEnum` type that occurs the most in the list of objects. I also need the other counts as well for display purposes, hence the usage of a simple `Dictionary(Of K, V)`.

I am looking for a LINQ query to give me back the `SomeEnum` key that occurs the most by looking at each keys number of occurences. Or perhaps there's an easier way of going about it.

I could do this:

```
    Return (From kvp As KeyValuePair(Of SomeEnum, Integer) _
            In Me.MyObjects Order By kvp.Value Descending _
            Select kvp).First().Key
```

But wouldn't the sorting be a more expensive operation than trying to wiggle Max() in there somehow? I'm a LINQ n00b, so any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `MaxBy` method in [MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq). There's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101841/linq-how-to-perform-max-on-a-property-of-all-objects-in-a-collection-and-retu) already on StackOverflow (it's in C#, though). You can use it like:

```
Return dic.MaxBy(Function(pair) pair.Value).Key
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this like this:

```
(From kvp In dic Select kvp Where kvp.Value = dic.Values.Max).First.Key
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I thought I'd provide my LINQ VB answer in case it helps others.

```
Return dic.Aggregate(Function(l, r) If(l.Value > r.Value, l, r)).Key
```