# Select X with Max(F(X))

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to write some AI for a game of checkers. I want to select the move with the highest board score.

Need something like this:

```
var bestMove = from m in validMoves
                where BoardScore(opp, board.Clone().ApplyMove(m)) is max
                select m
```

Except I can't figure out the "is max" part. Would prefer it returns a single item rather than an enumerable too.

---

Basically, the equivalent of this:

```
Move bestMove = null;
float highestScore = float.MinValue;
foreach (var move in validMoves)
{
    float score = BoardScore(opp, board.Clone().ApplyMove(move));
    if (score > highestScore)
    {
        highestScore = score;
        bestMove = move;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use LINQ to select object with minimum or maximum property value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914109/how-to-use-linq-to-select-object-with-minimum-or-maximum-property-value)

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188693/how-can-i-get-linq-to-return-the-object-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-given-prope

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ: How to perform .Max() on a property of all objects in a collection and return the object with maximum value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101841/linq-how-to-perform-max-on-a-property-of-all-objects-in-a-collection-and-ret)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't you basically already have this figured out? If you write your own extension method you can implement this functionality in typical LINQ fashion:

```
public static T MaxFrom<T, TValue>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, TValue> selector, IComparer<TValue> comparer)
{
    T itemWithMax = default(T);
    TValue max = default(TValue);

    using (var e = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (e.MoveNext())
        {
            itemWithMax = e.Current;
            max = selector(itemWithMax);
        }

        while (e.MoveNext())
        {
            T item = e.Current;
            TValue value = selector(item);
            if (comparer.Compare(value, max) > 0)
            {
                itemWithMax = item;
                max = value;
            }
        }
    }

    return itemWithMax;
}

public static T MaxFrom<T, TValue>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, TValue> selector)
{
    return source.MaxFrom(selector, Comparer<TValue>.Default);
}
```

This way you could just do:

```
var bestMove = validMoves
    .MaxFrom(m => BoardScore(opp, board.Clone().ApplyMove(m)));
```

Comment: Yeah... I just figured there had to be a built-in way to do it with Linq already. Not that hard to write myself :) Still, you get the check for doing my dirty work.

Answer (score 2):

```
var scores = from m in validMoves
                select BoardScore(opp, board.Clone().ApplyMove(m));
var bestMove = scores.Max();
```

EDIT:

I should have read more closely.  You can do:

```
var descendingMoves = validMoves.OrderByDescending(m=>BoardScore(opp, board.Clone().ApplyMove(m)));
var bestMove = descendingMoves.First();
```

But this is `O(n log n)`.  I found a [blog post](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2009/02/06/custom-c-3.0-linq-max-extension-method.aspx) with discussion on this issue.  It proposes a `Max` extension function that returns the maximum original value, rather than the transformed one.  Unfortunately, I don't know of a way to do this in LINQ.

Comment: Sorry, no. That's exactly the problem I'm having -- I found the `Max()` function, but it returns a `float`. I need the `move` with the highest score, not the score itself.

Comment: There's gotta be a way without sorting the whole list, no?

Comment: @Mark, you could use the code I linked, or just stick with the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
    float max = validMoves.Max(m => BoardScore(opp, board.Clone().ApplyMove(m)));
    var bestMove = validMoves
          .Where(m => BoardScore(opp, board.Clone().ApplyMove(m)) == max)
          .First();
```

Comment: Looks like it should work, but I'm pretty sure you're iterating over the moves twice, which shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to look at [`Enumerable.Max(TSource) Method (IEnumerable(TSource), Func(TSource, Single))`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534971(VS.90).aspx). i.e.:

```
var bestMove = validMoves.Max((m)=>BoardScore(opp, board.Clone().ApplyMove(m)));
```

If the scores are expensive to compute, you might compute all scores up-front, pairing them with their corresponding move, but I doubt this will be necessary. Example:

```
var scores = from m in validMoves
             select new {Move=m, Score=BoardScore(opp, board.Clone().ApplyMove(m))};
var bestMove = scores.Max(s=>s.Score).Move;
```

Comment: Neither of those solutions work. `Max()` returns a score. The second example won't even compile.