# Find max count of a list of custom types

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a mock application where an inheritance chain like
`Employee,Manager,President` etc.

The Employee class looks like

```
class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }

        public Employee() 
        { 
        }
    }
```

and the Manager class looks like

```
 class Manager : Employee
    {

        private List<Employee> employeesManaged = new List<Employee>();
        public List<Employee> EmployeesManaged
        {
            get { return employeesManaged; }
            set { employeesManaged = value; }
        }
    }
```

I would like to write a method that finds the manager who manages the most employees (whose EmployeesManaged.Count property is the largest).  I have two problems currently.

1. as you'll see in the code below I have to manually add each Manager to a List variable.  This isn't a long-term solution.  What would be an effective, concise manner of solving this?
2. my Linq syntax is incorrect.

I think the first problem is most pressing.  If there were 1000 Employee objects, how would I circumvent adding each one to a list?

```
 public static Manager  GetBestManager(List<Manager> managerList)
        {
            Manager m = managerList.Select(x => x.EmployeesManaged).Max();

        }
```

My Main method

```
Employee e = new Employee();
            e.EmployeeId = 101;
            e.FirstName = "Tom";
            e.LastName = "Jones";
            e.HireDate = DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(40));

            Employee e2 = new Employee();
            e2.EmployeeId = 102;


            Employee e3 = new Employee();
            e3.EmployeeId = 103;


            Manager m = new Manager();
            m.EmployeeId = 201;
            m.EmployeesManaged.Add(e);
            m.EmployeesManaged.Add(e2);

            Manager m2 = new Manager();
            m2.EmployeesManaged.Add(e3);

            List<Manager> mList = new List<Manager>();
            mList.Add(m);
            mList.Add(m2);
            Manager.GetBestManager(mList);
```

with the current syntax I get the error 'Cannot implicitly convert type Employee to Manager

Comment: The error you are getting is because of what @Ed-Chapel states where you are Getting a list<Employee> from your GetBestManager method and taking the Max of of that list<Employee> or a single Employee and then storing it in a manager object without having a method in your Manager class `public static implicit operator Manager(Employee e){}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ: How to perform .Max() on a property of all objects in a collection and return the object with maximum value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101841/linq-how-to-perform-max-on-a-property-of-all-objects-in-a-collection-and-ret)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) It depends on where the data is coming from. A database, file from disk, in memory collection. Often the `List` or whatever structure is determined by the source.

2) Your LINQ is getting the max number, not the `Manager` with the highest count. Try:

```
public static Manager GetBestManager(List<Manager> managerList)
{
    Manager m = managerList.OrderByDescending(x => x.EmployeesManaged.Count).First();
    return m;
}
```

Comment: This won't work as `Employee` doesn't implement `IComparable`... (`EmployeesManaged` is a `List<Employee>`, not an `int`)..

Answer (score 4):

Quick and perhaps dirtier solution that works:

```
return managerList
       .OrderByDescending(x => x.EmployeesManaged.Count)
       .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 3):

see my answer on this post:
[How can I get LINQ to return the object which has the max value for a given property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188693/how-can-i-get-linq-to-return-the-object-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-given-prop/3188804#3188804)

You can use the Aggregate function in System.Linq

Aggregate is faster because it simply runs through the collection once and takes the biggest as it goes.  OrderBy essentially has to do a bubble sort which is more costly.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be what you want:

```
public static Manager GetBestManager(this IList<Manager> managerList) {
    Func<Manager, int> getCount=x => x.EmployeesManaged.Count;
    return managerList.First(x => getCount(x)==managerList.Max(getCount));
}
```

If there're more than one manager have the same count of employees, this return the first one. The reason `FirstOrDefault` is not used, is because the max value is fetched from the list, we can always find a manager matches the max value except the collection is empty.

So, why use `FirstOrDefault` to return null rather than throw the exception to let the caller knows who passed an empty list?

Comment: Why throw an exception for something that isn't exceptional? There is no need for an exception here. Handle it gracefully.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: Then maybe `TryGetBestManager` with an `out` parameter is better.