# C#: Get Most Occurring Element in a List?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, list, loops

I have a list of type "Activity". And I need to find the most occurring element in that list. For example:

```
Activity a = new Activity();
a.Location = "USA";

Activity b = new Activity();
b.Location = "Sri Lanka";

Activity b = new Activity();
b.Location = "USA";

List<Activity> activityList = new List<Activity>();
activityList.add(a);
//......adding the rest of the objects as well.
```

Now I need to find the most occurring Location in this list. For example, the most occurring Location in the example above would be: USA.

I tried this:

```
            String currentLocation = "";
            String mostOccurring = "";
            int currentCount = 0;
            int highest = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < activityList.Count; i++)
            {
                currentLocation = activityList[i].Location;

                foreach (Activity activity in activityList)
                {
                    if (activity.Location.Equals(currentLocation))
                    {
                        currentCount++;
                        highest = currentCount;
                        //compare the highest count
                    }
                }
            }
```

But I got stuck and looks like it's not very efficient. It's in a ASP.NET web project, so efficiency is very important I think :) What is the most efficient way to get this done?

Comment: Also here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17180139/find-max-count-of-a-list-of-custom-types

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is trivially easy with Linq.

```
var query = activityList.GroupBy(x => x.Location)
    .Select(group => new {Location = group.Key, Count = group.Count()})
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count);

var item = query.First();

var mostfrequent = item.Location;
var mostfrequentcount = item.Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
activityList.GroupBy(a => a.Location)
            .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
            .First().Key;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do something similar and I used a `Dictionary`.

```
Dictionary<Location, int>  LocationCounter; 
. . .
public void CountLocations(Location thisPlace) {
    if (!LocationCounter(thisPlace)
        LocationCounter.Add(thisPlace, 1);
    else 
        LocationCounter[thisPlace]++;
}
```

[Here is a SO link about sorting by dictionary value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289/how-do-you-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)