# Linq using max to select a single value

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How to get the Property ID 3 ? There is a way to cast result to Conta?

```
List<Conta> contas = new List<Conta>();

contas.Add(new Conta { ID = 1, Saldo = 30 });
contas.Add(new Conta { ID = 2, Saldo = 50 });
contas.Add(new Conta { ID = 3, Saldo = 100 });

var result = contas.Where(c => c.Saldo == contas.Max(l => l.Saldo)) ;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Better way to return an object by max() in LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18766517/better-way-to-return-an-object-by-max-in-linq)

Comment: That's going to be O(N^2)...  At the very least grab the max value outside the `Where()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Single()` or `First()` if you only want one result:

```
var result = contas.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Saldo == contas.Max(l => l.Saldo));
```

This will returns the `Conta` object with maximum Saldo.

Answer (score 3):

```
var max = Users.OrderByDescending(x => x.Saldo).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Simple, short, and sweet. I like it! I had recently gone down a road of writing some long-winded 
"Max" function, just to realize this is perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You want a `MaxBy()` extension method. [These are widely available on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MoreLinq.Source.MoreEnumerable.MaxBy/).

Once you have that, the solution become simply:

```
List<Conta> contas = new List<Conta>();

contas.Add(new Conta { ID = 1, Saldo = 30 });
contas.Add(new Conta { ID = 2, Saldo = 50 });
contas.Add(new Conta { ID = 3, Saldo = 100 });

var result = contas.MaxBy(x => x.Saldo);

Console.WriteLine(result.ID);
```

Here's a sample implementation of MaxBy() (credits to Jon Skeet et al for this):

```
public static class EnumerableExt
{
    public static TSource MaxBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> selector)
    {
        return source.MaxBy(selector, Comparer<TKey>.Default);
    }

    public static TSource MaxBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> selector, IComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        using (IEnumerator<TSource> sourceIterator = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (!sourceIterator.MoveNext())
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequence was empty");
            }

            TSource max = sourceIterator.Current;
            TKey maxKey = selector(max);

            while (sourceIterator.MoveNext())
            {
                TSource candidate = sourceIterator.Current;
                TKey candidateProjected = selector(candidate);

                if (comparer.Compare(candidateProjected, maxKey) > 0)
                {
                    max = candidate;
                    maxKey = candidateProjected;
                }
            }

            return max;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.Where()` use `Single()` / `SingleOrDefault()` / `First()` / `FirstOrDefault()`

`Single` will throw an exception if there is 0 or more than 1 elements in the result.

`SingleOrDefault` will throw an exception if there is more than 1 element in the result.

`First` will throw if there are no results ( list is empty)

`FirstOrDefault` will throw if the list is null.