# Filter anonymous type collection

Tags: c#, linq, collections, anonymous-types

I have some little C# code which creates new anonymous type (collection). Entries in the collection differ only by Child.Value. What i am trying to achieve is: reduce the count of the parent-child pairs without child duplicates by getting the parent-child pairs with the highest value for each children in every parent. The children are distinguished by child Id.

```
var familyPairs = family
        .SelectMany(parent => parent.Children, (parent, child) => 
               new { 
                    Parent = parent, 
                    Child = child
                   })
        .OrderByDescending(pair => pair.Child.Value);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need single parent-child pair for each parent, then you can use simple select:

```
 family.Select(p => new { 
     Parent = p, 
     Child = p.Children.OrderByDescending(c => c.Value).FirstOrDefault()
 })
```

Or if you don't want pairs for parents without children - filter out child free parents:

```
 family.Where(p => p.Children.Any()).Select(p => new { 
     Parent = p, 
     Child = p.Children.OrderByDescending(c => c.Value).First()
 })
```

---

After your update it turns out that you need SelectMany, but you need to group children by id and select from each group child with max value:

```
 family.SelectMany(
   p => p.Children.GroupBy(c => c.Id)
                  .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(c => c.Value).First()),
   (p,c) => new { Parent = p, Child = c })
```

Comment: I will try it out. :)

Comment: Sorry, i edited my question if you come out with something about the edit. But i still gonna try this :)

Comment: @CeylanMumunKocabaş it's not clear from your edit - if you have several entries for same child in parent's children list, how do you distinguish two different children?

Comment: The children have ids, any child could have multiple entries with different values.

Answer (score 2):

If you want only the maximum child, sorting is a waste of time (n log n operations for the list of children). Instead, you should use the Aggregate() extension method to iterate through each list of children once to get the child with the maximum value.

```
family.Select(p => new { 
 Parent = p, 
 Child = p.Children.Aggregate((c1, c2) => c1.Value > c2.Value ? c1 : c2)})
```

See: [How can I get LINQ to return the object which has the max value for a given property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188693/how-can-i-get-linq-to-return-the-object-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-given-prop)

Comment: Also, I should point out that if multiple children share the maximum value, there is a big difference between the > and >= operators. The > operator will choose the last child with the max value, and >= will choose the first.