# How to LINQ get max object in a group?

Tags: c#, linq

How can I get the maximum element(the object itself) in each group, rather than the number itself?
I can only get the maximum value, not the object

```
        var maxValue = order.GroupBy(a => a.username).Select(a=>(a.Key, a.Max(k=>k.count)));
        Console.WriteLine("Max group = " + maxValue);
```

Comment: Does this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188693/how-can-i-get-linq-to-return-the-object-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-given-prop) helps you ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use LINQ to select object with minimum or maximum property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914109/how-to-use-linq-to-select-object-with-minimum-or-maximum-property-value)

Comment: `Select` returns `IEnumerable`, you should get a single item from it (by key for example)