# C# - Reading specific part of a File and splitting each line into an array or a list

Tags: c#, arrays, streamreader

First of all, Hi to everyone. I'm a beginner with C# and trying to do this homework. My problem is, reading a specific part of a .pdb (protein data bank) file and split that specific lines into an array or list. Then I will use it for a Forms App

So .pdb file index is looks like this;

```
HEADER    ANTIFREEZE 17-SEP-97   7MSI              
TITLE     TYPE III ANTIFREEZE PROTEIN ISOFORM HPLC 12                           
COMPND    MOL_ID: 1;                                                            
COMPND   2 MOLECULE: TYPE III ANTIFREEZE PROTEIN ISOFORM HPLC 12;       
SOURCE    MOL_ID: 1;                                                            
SOURCE   2 ORGANISM_SCIENTIFIC: MACROZOARCES AMERICANUS;

ATOM      1  N   MET A   0      18.112  24.345  32.146  1.00 51.10           N  
ATOM      2  CA  MET A   0      18.302  23.436  31.020  1.00 49.06           C  
ATOM      3  C   MET A   0      18.079  24.312  29.799  1.00 46.75           C  
ATOM      4  O   MET A   0      16.928  24.678  29.560  1.00 48.24           O  
ATOM      5  CB  MET A   0      17.257  22.311  31.008  1.00 48.14           C  
ATOM      6  N   ALA A   1      19.106  24.757  29.076  1.00 43.47           N

HETATM  491  O   HOH A 101      23.505  19.335  23.451  1.00 35.56           O  
HETATM  492  O   HOH A 102      19.193  19.013  25.418  1.00 12.73           O  
HETATM  493  O   HOH A 103       7.781  12.538  12.927  1.00 80.11           O
```

....
and goes on like this

I only need to read the lines that starts with "ATOM" keyword. Then I want to split their informations to variables and to an array or list. After that I want to print the maximum value of X Coordinate to a label.

For example;

```
ATOM     1  N   MET A   0      18.112  24.345  32.146  1.00 51.10           N
```

1 stands for atom number

N stands for atom name

MET stands for amino acid name

18.112 stands for X coordinate etc.

***WHAT I DID***

I used the codes from a similar question that was asked here before but i couldn't implement it to my project.
First I created a Class for variables

```
class Atom
{
    public int atom_no;
    public string atom_name;
    public string amino_name;
    public char chain;
    public int amino_no;
    public float x_coordinate;
    public float y_coordinate;
    public float z_coordinate;
    public float ratio;
    public float temperature;
}
```

For the main class; NOTE: I should mention that there's not single whitespace beetween variables. For example between "MET" and "A" there are extra 3 or 4 whitespaces. I've tried to remove them while reading file but I don't know if that worked..

```
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string filePath = @"path_of_file";
            string stringToSearch = @"ATOM";


      List<Atom> Atoms = new List<Atom>();
      using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
          {
          string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

             foreach (string line in lines)
             {
             if (line.Contains(stringToSearch))   // i have tried to read the parts that starts with ATOM
             {
               while (sr.Peek() >= 0)   //this while part is from the question asked before
               {
                   string[] strArray;
                   string line1 = sr.ReadLine();               // i've added theese 2 lines to remove the extra whitespaces 
                   var lineParts = line1.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                    strArray = line1.Split(' ');
                    Atom currentAtom = new Atom();
                    currentAtom.atom_no = int.Parse(strArray[0]);
                    currentAtom.atom_name = strArray[1];
                    currentAtom.amino_name = strArray[2];
                    currentAtom.chain = char.Parse(strArray[3]);
                    currentAtom.amino_no = int.Parse(strArray[4]);
                    currentAtom.x_coordinate = float.Parse(strArray[5]);
                    currentAtom.y_coordinate = float.Parse(strArray[6]);
                    currentAtom.z_coordinate = float.Parse(strArray[7]);
                    currentAtom.ratio = float.Parse(strArray[8]);
                    currentAtom.temperature = float.Parse(strArray[9]);

                    Atoms.Add(currentAtom);

                }

             }
         }


      }
      listBox1.DataSource = Atoms;
      listBox1.ValueMember = "atom_no";
      listBox1.DisplayMember = "atom_name";

}
```

I didn't add the part that i want to print the max value of X Coordinate to a label yet. I'm testing at this point with listbox. So when I run the code and press the button gives me "Input string was not in a correct format" error at the  `currentAtom.atom_no = int.Parse(strArray[0]);` line.

I know that my code looks like mess and sorry If I've stolen your time with this. I would be much appreciated if you guys can help me do this Forms app for my homework. If not, still thank you for reading it. Have a nice and healhty day..

Comment: Why are you using a stream reader AND `File.ReadAllLines`? `File.ReadAllLines` returns you all the lines from the file in an array. You can then filter them and split them after that.

Comment: `File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Where(line => line.Contains(stringToSearch))` Will return all the lines that contain your search term. Then you can use `Split` to split on whitespace and do what you want with the different parts of each line.

Comment: I've searched for, how i should get the parts that only starts with ATOM keyword found something that doesn't use stream reader and tried to mix the 2 codes. I don't know how to get the ATOM parts using StreamReader. Though I don't know that worked..

Comment: You can do it either way, but it doesn't really make sense to use *both at the same time*. `File.ReadAllLines` is simpler.

Comment: But there's multiple whitespaces between variables. Will Split method ignore the extra whitespaces?

Comment: Read [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1), try it and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to just use `File.ReadAllLines` to read the file, then filter out any lines that don't `StartWith` the `stringToSearch` text (using the `System.Linq` method `Where`), and finally select a new `Atom` from each line using the `Split` method (and remove empty entries) as you were doing, and finally returning them all with `ToList`:

```
List<Atom> Atoms = File.ReadAllLines(filePath)       // Read all the lines
    .Where(line => line.StartsWith(stringToSearch))  // Filter on our string
    .Select(line =>
    {
        // Split the line on the space character into an array 
        var strArray = line.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        // Return a new Atom for each line based on the array contents
        return strArray.Length < 10  // Ensure we have at least ten elements in the array
            ? null                   // If we don't have 10, return 'null'
            : new Atom               // Otherwise return a new atom from the array
            {
                atom_no = int.Parse(strArray[0]),
                atom_name = strArray[1],
                amino_name = strArray[2],
                chain = char.Parse(strArray[3]),
                amino_no = int.Parse(strArray[4]),
                x_coordinate = float.Parse(strArray[5]),
                y_coordinate = float.Parse(strArray[6]),
                z_coordinate = float.Parse(strArray[7]),
                ratio = float.Parse(strArray[8]),
                temperature = float.Parse(strArray[9])
            };
    })
    .ToList();                       // Return the items as a list
```

Comment: Thank you so much your for help and interest, I didn't give me any errors but I couldn't get the max value from x_coordinate. I'm not familiar with Linq, so can you please show me how can I get the max value of x_coordinate and print it out.

Comment: `int maxX = Atoms.Max(atom => atom.x_coordinate);`

Comment: Thank you sooo much for your help. Have a nice day Mr. Rufus..

Comment: I have a one more question, if you have time. So we have the maxX variable which has the Max value of X Coordinate, is there a way to get informations about the line of maxX value comes from? I mean which line has the maxX? Or what's the atom_name of that line?

Comment: Just search this site: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3188693/2052655