# Implementation of LINQ min with criteria on the source

Tags: c#, linq

If I want to get the min type of a collection, applying some criteria of the class values for a complex class with a lot of variables and fields, that cannot be done directly.

The closest attempt is:

```
public static TSource Min<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source);
```

For a simple class its clear:

```
public static void MaxEx3()
{
    Pet[] pets = { new Pet { Name="Barley", Age=8 },
                   new Pet { Name="Boots", Age=4 },
                   new Pet { Name="Whiskers", Age=1 } };

    Pet max = pets.Max();

    Console.WriteLine(
        "The 'maximum' animal is {0}.",
        max.Name);
}

/*
 This code produces the following output:

 The 'maximum' animal is Barley.
*/
```

But for a type with many fields there is no implementation such as: "return this specific type where the value of a determined fiel is minimal". For example from a `Vector3` collection the one with the minimum `z`.

Closest workaround would be returning a collection of your type like this (for a `Vector3` type):

```
OrderBy( vector => vector.z).Take(1).ToList();
```

I found this quite curious, as I find the source type return with a criteria in determined class field type or with any other predicate appliying logic the check of the class values themselves quite handy. Is there any explanation for this?

Comment: MoreLinq has `MinBy`. But the `OrderBy` solution works for most scenarios (including IQueryables) - so there is no real need for an "inbuilt" MinBy.

Comment: whats MoreLinq?

Comment: no need of. With orderby you can make it, but seems quite a handy implementation not to have by default. At least for me

Comment: Lots of things are handy. Adding something that is easily composed from other things can result in hiding more useful features. It is a tough balance.

Comment: `Select( vector => vector.z ).Min()` returns the min float, not the vector. My point is that I would like to have the vector with min z returned, by this I mean the vector type instance. Thanks

Comment: @rustyBucketBay Did you try `MinBy`?

Comment: `OrderBy( vector => vector.z).FirstOrDefault()` would return the first item of type `Vector3` from the order ordered collection.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188693/how-can-i-get-linq-to-return-the-object-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-given-prop

Comment: @mjwills my intention is not to incorporate external libraries to my project. Checking the code it seems to do the work. Thanks

Comment: This example with `Pet` class is not clear to me. C# can't just pick a field out of thin air to compare classes. Pet has to implement `IComparable` for this to work.

Comment: `MinBy` is definitely what you want.

Comment: `my intention is not to incorporate external libraries to my project. Checking the code it seems to do the work.` Copy the source code from MoreLinq then. I mean, I think your intention is foolish (and inconsistent - since you are clearly already using libraries), but the code is easy to copy and paste if you want to.

Comment: `C# can't just pick a field out of thin air to compare classes.` It isn't picking a field out of thin air - the OP wants it to choose based on the `z` value. Which `MinBy` does just fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is one `Enumerable.Min` implementations in LINQ that returns `TSource`. It requires that the class implements [`IComparable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.min?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Min__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) (in your case `IComparable<Pet>`) or older plain `IComparable`. In the method `CompareTo` you have to provide the code that can be used to determine the relation between any two instances of the class. This method has to provide "stable" results.