# LINQ- Max in where condition

Tags: c#, linq, max, where-clause

I have a class TaskWeekUI with this  definition:

```
 public class TaskWeekUI    {
   public Guid TaskWeekId { get; set; }
   public Guid TaskId { get; set; }
   public Guid WeekId { get; set; }
   public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
   public string PersianEndDate { get; set; }
   public double PlanProgress { get; set; }
   public double ActualProgress { get; set; }    }
```

and I wrote this query :

```
 TaskWeekUI ti =  tis.First( t => t.PlanProgress > 0 && t.EndDate ==  tis.Where(p => p.PlanProgress != null && p.PlanProgress > 0).Max(w => w.EndDate));
```

Is this query is true? Can I write my    query better than this?

Comment: excuse me , I edited and add query , I forgot it.

Comment: `p => p.PlanProgress != null` is not required in your `Where` clause

Comment: Tnx, But can I write a query for max in where condition?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101841/linq-how-to-perform-max-on-a-property-of-all-objects-in-a-collection-and-retu

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use LINQ to select object with minimum or maximum property value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914109/how-to-use-linq-to-select-object-with-minimum-or-maximum-property-value)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I think you want the one whose `PlanProgress > 0` has a most recent `EndDate`.

```
TaskWeekUI ti = tis.Where(t => t.PlanProgress > 0)
                   .OrderByDescending(t => t.EndDate)
                   .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: +1, nice clear solution without any extraneous exceptions introduced by using Max.

Comment: Tnx,I think it is a best any simple solution .

Comment: Isn't it a waste of time to sort the whole list just to get the item with  the highest `EndDate`? [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1101979/1219414) seems to be a better solution.

Comment: @JuanLuisSoldi: You are correct. The best solution should be O(n). But anyway it's acceptable, and it's the best solution base on build-in LINQ functions.

Answer (score 5):

This query seems to be correct from point of view of result obtained.

But in your inner query `tis.Where(p => p.PlanProgress != null && p.PlanProgress > 0).Max(w => w.EndDate)` is computed for each element in collection with `t.PlanProgress > 0`

So its a better way to obtain Max value outside of a query as follows:

```
var max = tis.Where(p => p.PlanProgress != null && p.PlanProgress > 0).Max(w => w.EndDate);
tis.First( t => t.PlanProgress > 0 && t.EndDate == max);
```

Going further p.PlanProgress != null is allways true since p.PlanProgress is not of Nullable type. So our code becomes like this:

```
var max = tis.Where(p => p.PlanProgress > 0).Max(w => w.EndDate);
    tis.First( t => t.PlanProgress > 0 && t.EndDate == max);
```

Or you can change a definition of your class and make p.PlanProgress of Nullable type:

```
public class TaskWeekUI    {
   public Guid TaskWeekId { get; set; }
   public Guid TaskId { get; set; }
   public Guid WeekId { get; set; }
   public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
   public string PersianEndDate { get; set; }
   public double? PlanProgress { get; set; }
   public double ActualProgress { get; set; }    
} 

var max = tis.Where(p => p.PlanProgress.HasValue && p.PlanProgress.Value > 0).Max(w => w.EndDate);
    tis.First( t => t.PlanProgress.HasValue && t.PlanProgress.Value > 0 && t.EndDate == max);
```

Comment: +1, the only thing I would change is the `First` to a `FirstOrDefault` unless he can guarantee that there will always be an item with `PlanProgress > 0`

Comment: +1, but I think 'collection.Max' throws an exception if 'collection' is empty, so there probably needs to be an additional check before setting 'max'. The collection will be empty if all PlanProgress <= 0. Since there are checks for PlanProgress > 0 I assume PlanProgress <= 0 is legal and an exception probably wouldn't be expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
     var max_Query =
                   (from s in db.Songs
                    join bk in db.Albums on s.BookId equals addAlbumDetailsViewModel.BookId
                    select s.SongId).Max();
                            max_Query++;
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need compare PlanProgress with null because double is struct type, it can't be null.

If you want TaskWeekUI with Max EndDate and positive PlanProgress You can try this code:

```
TaskWeekUI ti = tis.Where(t => t.PlanProgress > 0).Max(w => w.EndDate);
```

Comment: It'll end up assigning `DateTime` to `TaskWeekUI`

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'TaskWeekUI'