# OrderBy().Last() or OrderByDescending().First() performance

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I know that this probably is micro-optimization, but still I wonder if there is any difference in using

```
var lastObject = myList.OrderBy(item => item.Created).Last();
```

or

```
var lastObject = myList.OrderByDescending(item => item.Created).First();
```

I am looking for answers for Linq to objects and Linq to Entities.

Comment: Benchmark it over a million (several million?) iterations each, averaging several runs of each. You will then have your answer.

Comment: +1: Good Question: Personally I would use the latter. In SQL at least this would cause the process to complete once the first value had been found. The former option would need to fully order the list to find th last in the list. Not sure how this would apply to Linq though.

Comment: @Jon - It depends on the Linq implementation and how it translates the query to the underlying data store (if any).

Comment: EF would not support `Last()`, if I recall correctly. At any rate, in Linq-to-Objects, the difference would be the First/Last calls. The ordering *should* cost the same either way, and it *should* be the most expensive operation. `First()` only needs to iterate to the first item in the result, whereas `Last()` traverses the entire result sequence, however big it is.

Comment: In my opinion non will have overhead, since sorting is already done, it is just matter of picking one, should not be additional task.

Comment: @Anthony, does it iterate or pick from index?

Comment: @hungry, after an `OrderBy` operation, and barring an additional call to `ToList()` or `ToArray()` (which would render much of the discussion moot), additional operations would be working with an `IEnumerable`, the fact that it *could have originally been* an `IList` would be lost, as the ordered sequence *is not* the `IList`.

Comment: @Oded I would benchmark it, if I would think that there really is a significant performance difference. I was just fixing a bug in out system and come along this line (totally unrelated to the bug) and then asked the question just out of curiosity, not because of a real problem. Maybe someone with deep understanding of the internals of .Net already knows the answer to the question.

Comment: One interesting bit about `Last()` is that it tries to cast the `IEnumerable<T>` to `IList<T>` and return `list[count - 1]`. If it is not an `IList<T>`, then it does enumerate the entire collection to return the last element.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Assuming that both ways of sorting take equal time (and that's a big 'if'), then the first method would have the extra cost of doing a `.Last()`, potentially requiring a full enumeration.

And that argument probably holds even stronger for an SQL oriented LINQ.

Comment: I would expect `Last()` to be a constant time access in either case. For SQL it's `TOP 1` after an `ORDER BY ... DESC`. For an array it's just `list[list.Length - 1]`. Your thoughts?

Comment: @Yuck, you're ordering the sequence, which does not mutate the list. `list[lastIndex]` *does not* get you the highest or lowest ordered item. After the `OrderBy`, the `First()` or `Last()` is no longer working against the list directly, it's working against an `IEnumerable` sequence (strictly speaking in linq-to-objects terms).

Comment: @Yuck: Anthony is correct. `Last()` does try a cast to `IList<T>` first to be able to use the last index, but otherwise will enumerate. Your `select top 1 ... order by desc` would not be the same as `list[count-1]`. In one you're taking the first of a descending-ordered sequence, in the other you're taking the last of an ascending-ordered sequence *if* you can index into it. Your SQL example would be the same as `OrderByDescending().First()`, not `OrderBy().Last()`.

Answer (score 6):

(my answer is about Linq to Objects, not Linq to Entities)

I don't think there's a big difference between the two instructions, this is clearly a case of micro-optimization. In both cases, the collection needs to be sorted, which usually means a complexity of `O(n log n)`. But you can easily get the same result with a complexity of `O(n)`, by enumerating the collection and keeping track of the min or max value. Jon Skeet provides an implementation in his [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) project, in the form of a `MaxBy` extension method:

```
var lastObject = myList.MaxBy(item => item.Created);
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm sorry this doesn't directly answer your question, but...

Why not do a better optimization and use Jon Skeet's implementations of [MaxBy](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs) or [MinBy](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/MinBy.cs)?

That will be O(n) as opposed to O(n log n) in both of the alternatives you presented.

Answer (score 3):

In both cases it depends somewhat on your underlying collections. If you have knowledge up front about how the collections look before the order and select you could choose one over the other. For example, if you know the list is **usually** in an ascending (or mostly ascending) sorted order you could prefer the first choice. Or if you know you have indexes on the SQL tables that are sorted ascending. Although the SQL optimizer can probably deal with that anyway.

In a general case they are equivalent statements. You were right when you said it's micro-optimization.

Answer (score 3):

To give a more updated answer (since .Net is an evolving ecosystem), in .Net 6 the following has been introduced

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.maxby?view=net-6.0

Which for your question

```
var lastObject = myList.OrderBy(item => item.Created).Last();
```

would turn to

```
var lastObject = myList.MaxBy(item => item.Created);
```

executed in `O(n)` time

Answer (score 2):

Assuming OrderBy and OrderByDescending averages the same performance, taking the first element would permorm better than last when the number of elements is large.

Comment: See my comment to Henk Holterman, as your answers are similar. I would expect the operations to be the same.

Answer (score 2):

just my two cents: since `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending` have to iterate over all the objects anyway, there should be no difference.  however, if it were me i would probably just loop through all the items in a `foreach` with a compare to hold the highest comparing item, which would be an O(n) search instead of whatever order of magnitude the sorting is.

Comment: Not sure why this had no votes, functionally equivalent to max/min by and easier to understand.