# Linq get first row ordered by soonest date and where column B is not "Expired" or "Cancelled"

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list,

```
public Class Fruit
{
   public int id;
   public string status;
   public DateTime time;
   public .... other columns
}
```

I have a table like this,

```
458       2015-03-19 00:00:00.000   Completed
469       2015-03-23 00:00:00.000   Inprogress  
467       2015-02-21 00:00:00.000   Overdue 
470       2015-05-25 00:00:00.000   Completed
```

I want only 1 row ordered by soonest date but status either "Inprogress" or "Overdue", in above i want this,

```
467       2015-02-21 00:00:00.000   Overdue
```

I am not sure how but this i tried,

```
var fruits = fruits.order(p => p.time);
var // not sure whats next
```

Comment: So you want fruits that are inprogress or overdue ordered by time? Side Note: Making `status` an enum may make more sense

Comment: Does item 467 have a date with `2015`, or `2018`? Which is it?

Comment: You may want to consider using an `enum` for your `status` property...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `FirstOrDefault()` to select the first item that meets certain criteria, or `null` if there is no such item.

```
var firstNotExpired = fruits.OrderBy(f => f.time)
                            .FirstOrDefault(f => !(f.status == "Expired" || 
                                                   f.status == "Cancelled"));
```

That's nice and concise, but inefficient because it requires sorting the whole list. This is more efficient:

```
var firstNotExpired = fruits.Where(f => !(f.status == "Expired" || 
                                          f.status == "Cancelled"))
                            .OrderBy(f => f.time)
                            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `OrderBy()` with `First()`:

```
var result = fruits.Where(x => x.status == "Inprogress" || x.status == "Overdue")
                   .OrderBy(x => x.time)
                   .First();
```

Comment: @xanatos, That's a valid point and I pondered `FirstOrDefault` as well. Yet, the OP didn't mention Linq to Entities or database at all (only 'tables'). Also, sometimes you *do* want an exception to be thrown in case nothing found.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiousity, I'll mention https://stackoverflow.com/a/6680893/613130 :
if you are doing a LINQ-to-Objects (so your `fruits` isn't a db) doing an `OrderBy` is a `O(nlogn)` operation that in this case is useless... Using https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/ (with some little changes, because `MinBy()` doesn't support empty enumerables):

```
var firstNotExpired = fruits.Where(f => !(f.status == "Expired" || f.status == "Cancelled"))
                            .MinByOrDefault(f => f.time);
```

and

```
public static class EnumerableTools
{
    public static TSource MinByOrDefault<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> selector)
    {
        IComparer<TKey> comparer = Comparer<TKey>.Default;

        using (var sourceIterator = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (!sourceIterator.MoveNext())
            {
                // Empty source
                return default(TSource);
            }

            var min = sourceIterator.Current;
            var minKey = selector(min);

            while (sourceIterator.MoveNext())
            {
                var current = sourceIterator.Current;
                var currentKey = selector(current);

                if (comparer.Compare(currentKey, minKey) < 0)
                {
                    min = current;
                    minKey = currentKey;
                }
            }

            return min;
        }
    }
}
```

This is guaranteed to be `O(n)` in time and `O(1)` in space (no sorting is necessary, and no extra space is allocated)