# Finding Mode of Array C# ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im currently coding a statistics calculator for Mean, Median, Mode, Max and Min
However I am not able to understand the code required for the mode method, I have a Array called arryval which contains the numbers. How to i filter through this array and return a value at the end

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer help you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8260598/1166719

Comment: Firstly, show us the code. Secondly, if you are trying to find them mean, as per the title, why have you said "*I am not able to understand the code required for the mode method*"

Answer (score -1):

Using linq you can just group by every element, get the amount of elements in every group and then get the element with the max amount of elements

```
var groups = x.GroupBy(v => v);
int maxCount = groups.Max(g => g.Count());
int mode = groups.First(g => g.Count() == maxCount).Key;
```

Comment: Thanks but its just the mode method i need to complete, I have completed the other methods