# LINQ Using Max() to select a single row

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm using LINQ on an IQueryable returned from NHibernate and I need to select the row with the maximum value(s) in a couple of fields.

I've simplified the bit that I'm sticking on. I need to select the one row from my table with the maximum value in one field.

```cs
var table = new Table { new Row(id: 1, status: 10), new Row(id: 2, status: 20) }

from u in table
group u by 1 into g
where u.Status == g.Max(u => u.Status)
select u
```

This is incorrect but I can't work out the right form.

BTW, what I'm actually trying to achieve is approximately this:

```cs
var clientAddress = this.repository.GetAll()
    .GroupBy(a => a)
    .SelectMany(
            g =>
            g.Where(
                a =>
                a.Reference == clientReference && 
                a.Status == ClientStatus.Live && 
                a.AddressReference == g.Max(x => x.AddressReference) && 
                a.StartDate == g.Max(x => x.StartDate)))
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

I started with the above lambda but I've been using LINQPad to try and work out the syntax for selecting the Max().

**UPDATE**

Removing the GroupBy was key.

```cs
var all = this.repository.GetAll();

var address = all
            .Where(
                a =>
                a.Reference == clientReference && 
                a.Status == ClientStatus.Live && 
                a.StartDate == all.Max(x => x.StartDate) &&
                a.AddressReference == all.Max(x => x.AddressReference))
            .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101841/linq-how-to-perform-max-on-a-property-of-all-objects-in-a-collection-and-ret

Comment: @M.Babcock there was a good answer quite far down in that question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6330485/444244

Comment: There are much better ones than that...

Comment: Take a look at [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1101979/490018).

Comment: @Serge I agree that [morelinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) would be best but I'm afraid this project has impediments to adding new libraries.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use LINQ to select object with minimum or maximum property value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914109/how-to-use-linq-to-select-object-with-minimum-or-maximum-property-value)

Answer (score 279, accepted):

I don't see why you are grouping here.

Try this:

```
var maxValue = table.Max(x => x.Status)
var result = table.First(x => x.Status == maxValue);
```

An alternate approach that would iterate `table` only once would be this:

```
var result = table.OrderByDescending(x => x.Status).First();
```

This is helpful if `table` is an `IEnumerable<T>` that is not present in memory or that is calculated on the fly.

Comment: I took out the grouping and found I could get it working:      `from u in User_Accounts
where u.Status == User_Accounts.Max(y => y.Status)
select u`

Comment: You can also nest the lambda syntax:

`table.First(x => x.Status == table.Max(x => x.Status))`

Comment: @LandonPoch: That's not a good idea, as this would calculate the maximum N times with N being the number of items in `table`.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: Good catch! That would in fact calculate the max per every row in the table. My bad.

Comment: For the second approach, it may only iterate once, but it's using a sort, which will be O(n log n), right? The first way is just 2 O(n) operations.

Comment: Actually, my previous comment was not quite accurate: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/5.0/orderby-firstordefault-complexity-increase. .NET Core 1-3 made it so that calling `First` made it O(n), later it was revised so that it was O(n log n), but optimized to call the predicate fewer than `n` times if not needed, which apparently is better overall. This seems consistent with the results I've been getting from testing.

Answer (score 23):

You can also do:

```
(from u in table
orderby u.Status descending
select u).Take(1);
```

Answer (score 14):

You can group by status and select a row from the largest group:

```
table.GroupBy(r => r.Status).OrderByDescending(g => g.Key).First().First();
```

The first `First()` gets the first group (the set of rows with the largest status); the second `First()` gets the first row in that group.
If the status is always unqiue, you can replace the second `First()` with `Single()`.

Answer (score 7):

Addressing the first question, if you need to take several rows grouped by certain criteria with the other column with max value you can do something like this:

```
var query =
    from u1 in table
    join u2 in (
        from u in table
        group u by u.GroupId into g
        select new { GroupId = g.Key, MaxStatus = g.Max(x => x.Status) }
    ) on new { u1.GroupId, u1.Status } equals new { u2.GroupId, Status = u2.MaxStatus}
    select u1;
```

Answer (score 3):

What about using `Aggregate`?

It's better than

1. Select max
2. Select by max value

since it only scans the array once.

```cs
var maxRow = table.Aggregate(
  (a, b) => a.Status > b.Status ? a : b  // whatever you need to compare
);
```

Comment: The question clearly states "LINQ on an IQueryable returned from NHibernate". That requires a method that can be translated into SQL. I.e. not `Aggregate`.

Comment: In other words, Aggregate is executed immediately, not deferred. It's executed in memory on the running code, not as a SQL command executed in the DB
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/classification-of-standard-query-operators-by-manner-of-execution

Answer (score 0):

**Simply** in one line:

```
var result = table.First(x => x.Status == table.Max(y => y.Status));
```

Notice that there are two action.
the inner action is for finding the max value,
the outer action is for get the desired object.

Comment: This method was discussed in the comments to the accepted answer where it was pointed out it was a bad idea.

Comment: It is a bad idea because table.Max(y => y.Status) is going to be invoked once for each item in table, which is far from being optimal.

Comment: Far-from optimal meaning O(n ^ 2), performing worse than the sorting solution and the double-scan solution.

Answer (score 0):

More one example:

Follow:

```
 qryAux = (from q in qryAux where
            q.OrdSeq == (from pp in Sessao.Query<NameTable>() where pp.FieldPk
            == q.FieldPk select pp.OrdSeq).Max() select q);
```

Equals:

```
 select t.*   from nametable t  where t.OrdSeq =
        (select max(t2.OrdSeq) from nametable t2 where t2.FieldPk= t.FieldPk)
```