# Using LINQ nested query get latest rows for update

Tags: c#, sql, linq

LINQ experts, I am looking to update the latest data on a per user basis, to explain say I have a table "dummy":

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dummy](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TimeStamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TransAmount] [decimal](10, 4) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

What I am looking to do is get the latest record for each UserId, using SQL I would use something like:

```
select * from dummy d1 join 
(
select max(id) as id 
from dummy d1
Join (select distinct userid from dummy) d2 on d1.userid = d2.userid
group by d1.userid)
as d2 on d1.id = d2.id
```

but I am looking to do this using LINQ.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that second nested query is necessary since you're already grouping by userid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following would work as well using method syntax:

```
var maxIds = dummy.GroupBy(d => d.UserId, (userId, dummyGroup) => 
dummyGroup.Max(dg => dg.Id));
```

If you want the entire record, you can use the following:

```
var recordsWithMaxId = dummy.GroupBy(d => d.UserId, (userId, dummyGroup) => 
dummyGroup.OrderByDescending(dg => dg.Id).First());
```

Answer (score 5):

What you're looking for is GroupBy in LINQ. Something along these lines:

```
var users = from d in dummy
            group d by d.userId into u
            select new 
            {
               UserId = u.Key
               Id = u.Max(i => i.Id)
            };
```

Comment: An excellent answer although I was looking for the complete record as in the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

Check that :

```
var maxID = dummy.Max(i => i.UserID)
var row = table.First(i => i.UserID == maxID);
```

reference from : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114863/linq-using-max-to-select-a-single-row)

Comment: Um, how does this answer the question? OP is looking for the `the latest record for each UserId`, which has nothing to do with `Max of UserID`. Your linked answer only expects to return one row.