# LINQ Using Max() to select a single value of a row

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I need to select from my table the maximum value with linq.

**SQL:**

```
Select MAX(number) AS Maximo FROM my_table
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114863/linq-using-max-to-select-a-single-row

Comment: @Vladimir there wants the whole row. but here he wants only the value, much simpler ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
YourContext.YourTable.Max(x => x.number)
```