# Select max as second criteria with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

i'm trying to get all rows who has some field = max of that field

to be able to explain my doubt, I will leave an example of model

```
class model
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order=0)]
    public int Key { get; set; }     

    [Key]
    [Column(Order=1)]
    public int Revision { get; set; }

    public string OtherStuff { get; set; }    
}
```

A data example could be

```
|Key|Revision   |Otherstuff |
|1  |1          |A          |
|1  |2          |B          |
|1  |3          |C          |
|2  |1          |D          |
|2  |2          |E          |
|3  |1          |F          |
```

What i want to get:

```
|Key|Revision   |Otherstuff |
|1  |3          |C          |
|2  |2          |E          |
|3  |1          |F          |
```

I try the solutions i could find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114863/linq-using-max-to-select-a-single-row) but i couldn't make it work

This it what i got

```
IQueryable<model> data = dbContext.model;

data = data.GroupBy(x => x.Revision ).OrderByDescending(x => x.Key).SelectMany(x => x)

//Applying logic to filter the data 
data = data.Where(...)
```

My main problem is that it is a filtering method, and when using SelectMany the database is disposed and I can not continue modifying the list as I need

How i supose to do it?

Thanks!

**Solved**

```
data = data.GroupBy(x => x.Key).Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(d => d.Revision).FirstOrDefault());
```

Thanks all responses!

Comment: Remove the SelectMany.  The GroupBy returns a two dimensional array data[key, values[]].  The Where or Select  then enumerates through the keys.  You can then have a second Select like following : data.Select(x => x.Where(y => .....)).SelectMany(x => x).ToList();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = data.GroupBy(x => x.Revision).Select(x => x.First())
```

if you try to do any other operations after the first query (such as select a subset of columns) - you need to use x.FirstOrDefault

Comment: with a bit of mutation it managed to solve my problem, thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
data = data..GroupBy(x => x.Key).OrderByDescending(x => x.Key).Select(x => new { Key = x.Key, Revision = x.Count() });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = data.GroupBy(x => x.Revision).Select(revisitions => revisitions.OrderByDescending(x => x.Key).First())
```