# Get from a List<t> the record with the maximum value of a specific property

Tags: c#, linq, max

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LINQ: How to perform .Max() on a property of all objects in a collection and return the object with maximum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101841/linq-how-to-perform-max-on-a-property-of-all-objects-in-a-collection-and-ret)

I have the following class:

```
class Product
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public DateTime ActivationDate { get; set; }
}
```

Then I create and fill a  `List<Product>` and I would like to get the `ProductName` from the `Product` with the latest `ActivationDate`.

```
Product.Where(m => m.ActivationDate == Max(m.ActivationDate)).Select(n => n.ProductName)

Product.Max(m => m.ActivationDate).Select(n => n.ProductName)
```

but bot methods do not work. Does anybody know a way to achieve this task?

Comment: How large is the list? It is pretty easy to write a `MaxBy` (or similar), but not worth it for small lists. For large lists, it *would* be worth it. The difference is `O(n)` vs `O(n^2)` (or maybe `O(n*log(n))`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can `OrderByDescending` the `List<Product>` on the ActivationDate Field and then take `FirstOrDefault()`

```
Product.OrderByDescending(p => p.ActivationDate).FirstOrDefault();
```

For a more simpler version there is an extension method

[`MaxBy`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs)

```
Product.MaxBy(p => p.ActivationDate);
```

Comment: Yup, the MoreLinq one is the way to go here.

Comment: Was this downvoted coz this was not an optimal solution ?

Comment: @V4Vendetta Yup, reversing my downvote now due to the edit.

Comment: Yup, same here. That said, it was probably still more efficient than some of the other answers :)

Comment: Yes. I just removed the downvote, the MaxBy is perfect for this.

Answer (score 4):

If you can do this:

```
class Product : IComparable<Product>
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public DateTime ActivationDate { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(Product other)
    {
        return this.ActivationDate.CompareTo(other.ActivationDate);
    }
}
```

Then it is just this:

```
var max = products.Max(p => p).ProductName;
```

Comment: +1 Never thought of that. It'd be great if there was an overload of `Max` that took an IComparator so you could have different comparisons. (BTW do you mean `.ProductName` in your last line?)

Comment: Best solution. You could omit the lambda parameter though: `var max = products.Max().ProductName`.

Answer (score 2):

Here we go; a single pass of the list:

```
public static TSource MaxBy<TSource,TValue>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource,TValue> selector)
{
    using(var iter = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iter.MoveNext())
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Empty sequence");
        var max = selector(iter.Current);
        var item = iter.Current;
        var comparer = Comparer<TValue>.Default;
        while(iter.MoveNext())
        {
            var tmp = selector(iter.Current);
            if(comparer.Compare(max, tmp) < 0)
            {
                item = iter.Current;
                max = tmp;
            }
        }
        return item;
    }
}
```

then:

```
var maxObj = list.MaxBy(x => x.SomeProp);
```

This is more efficient than doing an `OrderBy`, for example, which needs to actually *sort* the data, rather than just sweep over it once.

Comment: I know it is the same name as in MoreLinq, but I find it unfortunate.
the important thing, which should be part of the name, is whether it returns First item with the max value, or Last item with the max value.

Comment: Or maybe it could return all objects with the max value.

Comment: @Marc - interesting last point. If LINQ did a selection sort, then `OrderBy.First` would essentially do the same as `MaxBy`, but you could then select the next few items too.

Comment: @Rawling the work involved in an OrderBy is **much** more significant than just iterating over the data once

Comment: @TomasGrosup here's the wonderful thing; if you copy and paste it, I won't mind if you change the name ;p

Comment: @Tomas to get *all* values with a given value, you'd need to buffer too (at least the items that match). That *might* not be a problem, it could be in some cases. Easy to do, of course - I'm just remarking.

Comment: @Marc Exactly - if you only wanted the first few, it should be more efficient to implement a deferred-execution selection-sort based `OrderBy` and then `.Take` as many as you needed, than to do a non-deferrable quicksort-based `OrderBy`.

Answer (score 1):

How about writting an extension Function called Max which internally does the simple search logic presented by Branko Dimitrijevic.

```
/// <param name="comparer">Func<T current, T currentMax, long> </param>
    public static T Max<T>(this List<T> collection, Func<T, T, long> comparer) where T : class
    {
        T max_product = null;
        collection.ForEach(c =>
        {
            if (max_product == null || comparer(c, max_product) > 0)
                max_product = c;
        });

        return max_product;
    }
```

Call this function as:

```
string maxProductName = products.Max<Product>((currentProduct, currentMaxProduct) =>
        {
            // Basically any logic
            return currentMaxProduct.ActivationDate.CompareTo(currentProduct.ActivationDate);
        }).ProductName;
```

Answer (score 0):

A non-LINQ solution is easy enough, in case you need it in only one place so the general [MaxBy](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs) would be an overkill:

```
Product max_product = null;

foreach (var product in products) {
    if (max_product == null || max_product.ActivationDate < product.ActivationDate)
        max_product = product;
}

// Use `max_product`...
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this one

```
ProductList.Where(m => m.ActivationDate == ProductList.Max(pl => pl.ActivationDate)).FirstOrDefault().ProductName;
```

Comment: At least store the max once and then check against it. Otherwise you're looping through the list up to once for each item in the list.