# How to get the key when using linq Max() method

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<>` which contains several strings. For example `{a1, a2, a15, a3, a16, a1}`. I want to get the string with the Max number (a16). I tried using Where() and Max() but then it will return the maximum value (16), where I want to return the string (a16).
I guess I could do it with an additional `Where()` and `contains()` but I was wondering if I could do it in a simpler way.

Here is the code example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace linq_example
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string> {"b1", "a1", "a2","a9", "a16", "a1", "a5" , "b20"};
            var max = list.Where(i => i.IndexOf("a") != -1).Max(a => Convert.ToInt32(a.Substring(1)));
            Console.WriteLine(max.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This program will print 16 where I wanted to print a16

Comment: Is it a typo that the list in your example actually does not contain `a16` but contains `16`? If you have strings in a `List<string>` then LINQ will not magically convert them to `ints`. You should be getting the `string` which has the "maximum" value (check out sorting rules for strings).

Comment: It sounds like you're almost there. If you post your code, it will probably be very easy to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var biggest = list.OrderByDescending(x => Convert.ToInt32(a.Substring(1)).First();
```

Note that LINQ OrderBy is "lazily" evaluated. It will pick only first element and won't sort completetly the list. Overhead is comparable to Max(). That's the beauty of LINQ.

Alternatively, you can take a look at this link: [LINQ: How to perform .Max() on a property of all objects in a collection and return the object with maximum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101841/linq-how-to-perform-max-on-a-property-of-all-objects-in-a-collection-and-ret)

MoreLINQ has MaxBy() that will allow you to do it easily.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

add these namespaces:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

You can use `regex` to get only the part number of string and convert this result to a int, for sample:

```
var max = list.Max(x => int.Parse(Regex.Match(x, @"\d+")));
```

Comment: You can save one line by using : Max(x => int.Parse(x.Replace("a", string.Empty)))

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough... I've added some code sample. Your solution gives the same answer.

Comment: @AlexH, It does not ensure that the item on the list if a number, that's the reason I use `Where` and `int.TryParse` to filter before casting to int.

Comment: @FelipeOriani, my remark wasn't clear enough; you can replace the Select with a Max to save one line : (with your edit) var max = list.Max(x => int.Parse(Regex.Match(x, @"\d+")))

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
List<string> list = new List<string> { "a1", "a2", "a15", "a3", "a16", "a1" };
var largest = list.OrderBy(s => int.Parse(Regex.Match(s, @"\d+").ToString())).Last();
```

Comment: I thought of using this approach but I think it will have some performance penalty since you now need to sort the entire list and not just finding the max value.

Comment: Ya that might be true. But, `max` might also do the same thing internally.