# how to find and display the most repeating words in a string using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

```
  String ss = "lijo is lijom is lijo fdf"; //here two words "is" and "lijo" is repeating two times so my output will be 
                          output   : lijo 
                                      is
```

**I tried Like this**

```
 var count=words.GroupBy(g=>g).Max(k=>k.Count());
//finding the max repeating elements count =2


 var res = words.GroupBy(s => s).Where(g => g.Count() == count).Select(s => s);
```

here i have tried by first finding the max count of repeating words. and assign this value in another query.

i need to know if we can write both this queries together as one query. as a subquery
how to do this in a different way ?
using subquery or any other easy method?

Comment: why down voting...what wrong with question please atleast give a comment

Comment: this question is not a repetition .using max property we cannot find the repeating words..max will check with the ascci value of string...

Comment: please the check question clearly those who are saying its repeating..i have goggled a lot but i didnt get an answer...that's why i asked here..max property will always return one value.but here i need all the words that are repeating maximum.

Comment: Please consider upvoting, commenting or marking as answer for any answer that helped you.

Answer (score 2):

There is an overload of group by that can easily give you your counts.

```
String ss = "lijo is lijom is lijo fdf";
var words = ss.Split();
var query = words.GroupBy(
            word => word,
            (key, counts) => new
            {
                Word = key,
                Count = counts.Count()
            });
```

To finish this off, I'd recommend using a [MaxBy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1101979/2589202) extension.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var l = words.GroupBy(x => x).Select(y => new{key = y.Key, count = y.Count()}).ToList();
var max = l.OrderByDescending(y=>y.count).First().count;
var result = l.Where(x => x.count == max).Select(y=>y.key);
```

`l` simply gets the pairs of words and their frequencies. `max` is the maximum count from `l`. `result` will give you the words which have the maximum frequency.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/OEP31645)