# Is there a LINQ statement that can select an object from an enumeration based on a max of one of its properties?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

We have a collection of objects with a count property as follows...

```
Item A : Count 4
Item B : Count 2
Item C : Count 5 <-- We want this one
Item D : Count 3

(Note the actual list can have hundreds of items.)
```

We're trying to write a LINQ statement that returns 'Item C' since it has the highest value for Count.

**Note: We don't want the count. We want the item with the highest count.**

Of course this can be easily done with simple looping constructs, but I'm wondering if it can be achieved purely with LINQ.

Only thing I can think of is to use the Aggregate statement like this...

```
var item = Screen.Items
            .Aggregate( (highestItem, nextItem) => 
                highestItem = (highestItem == null)
                    ? nextItem
                    : (highestItem.Count < nextItem.Count)
                        ? nextItem
                        : highestItem);
```

Seems verbose though.  Is there a different, shorter way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101841/linq-how-to-perform-max-on-a-property-of-all-objects-in-a-collection-and-ret

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the default `Max()` LINQ extensions if you just need the `Count` value (I assume `pairs` is `ICollection<KeyValuePair<Item, int>>`).

```
var highestCount = pairs.Max(pair => pair.Value);
```

Or you can add MoreLINQ nuget and use `MaxBy()` extension to get `Item`:

```
var itemWithHighestCount = pairs.MaxBy(pair => pair.Value).Key;
```

**UPDATE:**

Just wanted to share some performance results. For a `List<object, long>` collection with 10 million elements and random `long` values (average time for 10 runs):

- `Aggregate` takes **430 ms**
- `OrderBy` takes **5,991 ms**
- `MaxBy` from MoreLINQ takes **231 ms**

Comment: MoreLINQ is an add-on?  What about built-in LINQ functions?  Only thing I can think of is .Aggregate like I showed above.

Comment: moreLINQ is a library you'd have to include in your program. It's not part of .NET Framework. There is nothing like this built in. You could either use your `Aggregate` solution or use `OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).First();`

Comment: Yeah, MoreLINQ is a nuget that our will need to add (or you can add it as DLL). If you don't want to use it that `OrdeyBy()` is probably your best solution. It will be faster than `Aggregate()` and more readable.

Comment: @NikolaiSamteladze I wouldn't expect `OrderBy` to be faster, because `Aggregate` can be done in *O(n)* time, and sorting required at least *O(n*log(n))`

Comment: I was just thinking the same thing (r.e. Aggregate vs. OrderBy.)  Doesn't the Aggregate loop over the list one time whereas OrderBy has to do it several times?

Comment: You are right. `OrderBy` would be much slower. I does much more than just finding the maximum.

Comment: Timed it actually. On `List<object, long>` with 10 million elements `OrderBy` takes 5991 ms on average, `Aggregate` takes 430 ms and `MoreLINQ` takes 231 ms.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's Reactive Framework team wrote some very nice LINQ extensions. Do a NuGet for "Ix-Main" (stands for "Interactive Extensions") and you can then do this:

```
var item = list.MaxBy(i => i.Count);
```