# What is faster in finding element with property of maximum value

Tags: c#, performance, linq, collections

Commonly, to find element with property of max value I do like this

```
var itemWithMaxPropValue = collection.OrderByDescending(x => x.Property).First();
```

But is it good way from performance point of view? Maybe I should do something like this?

```
var maxValOfProperty = collection.Max(x => x.Property);
var itemWithMaxPropValue = collection
                                 .Where(x => x.Property == maxValueOfProperty).First();
```

Comment: I will go with `Max` since it is designed specially for it... Sorting to find max value seems to be too much... Also, I wouldn't use `Where` for finding the max, but `Single`

Comment: `OrderByDescending` / Quicksort should be O(n^2) and `Max` is O(n) with `Where` O(n) - so the second approch should be faster

Comment: see https://www.nuget.org/packages/MoreLinq.Source.MoreEnumerable.MaxBy/ for in-memory use (doesn't translate to sql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both solutions are not very efficient. First solution involves sorting whole collection. Second solution requires traversing collection two times. But you can find item with max property value in one go without sorting collection. There is MaxBy extension in [MoreLINQ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) library. Or you can implement same functionality:

```
public static TSource MaxBy<TSource, TProperty>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TProperty> selector)
{
    // check args        

    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())            
            throw new InvalidOperationException();

        var max = iterator.Current; 
        var maxValue = selector(max);
        var comparer = Comparer<TProperty>.Default;

        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            var current = iterator.Current;
            var currentValue = selector(current);

            if (comparer.Compare(currentValue, maxValue) > 0)
            {
                max = current;
                maxValue = currentValue;
            }
        }

        return max;
    }
}
```

Usage is simple:

```
var itemWithMaxPropValue = collection.MaxBy(x => x.Property);
```

Answer (score 5):

Sorting is `N * log (N)` while Max has `N` only time complexity, so `Max` is *faster*. What you're looking for is `ArgMax` function which *Linq* doesn't provide, so I suggest implementing it, e.g:

```
  public static class EnumerableExtensions {
    public static T ArgMax<T, K>(this IEnumerable<T> source, 
                                 Func<T, K> map, 
                                 IComparer<K> comparer = null) {
      if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, source))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
      else if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, map))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("map");

      T result = default(T);
      K maxKey = default(K);
      Boolean first = true;

      if (null == comparer)
        comparer = Comparer<K>.Default;

      foreach (var item in source) {
        K key = map(item);

        if (first || comparer.Compare(key, maxKey) > 0) {
          first = false;
          maxKey = key;
          result = item;
        }
      }

      if (!first)
        return result;
      else
        throw new ArgumentException("Can't compute ArgMax on empty sequence.", "source");
    }
  }
```

So you can put it simply

```
  var itemWithMaxPropValue = collection
    .ArgMax(x => x.Property);
```

Answer (score 3):

I will go with `Max` since it is specifically designed for that purpose. Sorting to find `Max` value seems to be too much.

Also, I wouldn't use `Where` for finding the max, but `Single` - since what we need here is but a `Single` value.

```
var maxValOfProperty = collection.Max(x => x.Property);
var itemWithMaxPropValue = collection
                            .Single(x => x.Property == maxValueOfProperty);
```

Or alternatively using `First` (if the collection contains duplicates of max value)

```
var maxValOfProperty = collection.Max(x => x.Property);
var itemWithMaxPropValue = collection
                            .First(x => x.Property == maxValueOfProperty);
```

Or, using [MoreLINQ](https://code.google.com/archive/p/morelinq/) (as suggested by [Kathi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5210934/kathi)), you could do it with `MaxBy`:

```
var itemWithMaxPropValue = collection.MaxBy(x => x.Property);
```

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101841/linq-how-to-perform-max-on-a-property-of-all-objects-in-a-collection-and-ret), on answer by [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).

Comment: You might want to use `First` instead of `Single` if the collection contains more than one item (that has the max value for the property) and OP doesn't care about which one to take in this case.

Comment: @YacoubMassad you are right, that certainly is a valid alternative.

Comment: Please note also that if you combine the two lines, then `collection.Max(x => x.Property)` might be evaluated multiple times.

Comment: @Kathi you mean this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.maxby(v=vs.103).aspx ? it seems like it is not typical LINQ, I am not sure of its performance...

Comment: @Ian if that's MoreLINQ then that's what I meant but also check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1101931/5210934, you'll find the `MaxBy(..)` thing also in an answer there

Comment: @Kathi ok, I put up the alternative, referring to you. ;) it seems to be good solution. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Ian Mathematically, the Aggregate - Solution seems to be the best one as you'll be only traversing through the list once..

Comment: @Kathi ignoring all other delays caused by it, then it could probably be. ;) Only a little more complicated to see...

Answer (score 1):

The maximum element under some specified function can also be found by means of the following two functions.

```
static class Tools
{
    public static T ArgMax<T, R>(T t1, T t2, Func<T, R> f)
    where R : IComparable<R>
    {
        return f(t1).CompareTo(f(t2)) > 0 ? t1 : t2;
    }

    public static T ArgMax<T, R>(this IEnumerable<T> Seq, Func<T, R> f)
    where R : IComparable<R>
    {
        return Seq.Aggregate((t1, t2) => ArgMax<T, R>(t1, t2, f));
    }
}
```

The solution above works as follows; the first overload of `ArgMax` takes a comparator as an argument which maps both instances of `T` to a type which implements comparability; a maximum of these is returned. The second overload takes a sequence as an argument and simply aggregates the first function. This is the most generic, framework-reusing and structurally sound formulation for maximum search I am aware of; searching the minimum can be implemented in the same way by changing the comparison in the first function.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little bit surprised that no one mentioned the `Aggregate` method. `Aggregate` lets you iterate a collection and return an aggregate value.

An ArgMax function can be implemented in this way:

```
var maxItem = collection.Aggregate((max, next) => next.Property.CompareTo(max.Property) > 0 ? next : max);
```

This function will iterate all over the collection and aggregate the item that has the largest `Property`. This implementation is `O(N)` which is good.

Please note that the `Property` getter (or the compared value in general) is called `2N` times so don't do this when the value computation is heavy. You can avoid this with another iteration over the array or use the @Sergey Berezovskiy answer which suits all the cases.

But if you need it for simple values, this is a one-line efficient solution