# How to find maximum value in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, numbers, max

```
var max=0.0d;
for(inc=0;inc<array.length;inc++){
if(max<array[inc])
max=array[inc];
}
```

I want to find out the maximum value of an array.The above code is generally we used to find out maximum value of an array.

But this code will return `0` if the array contains only `negative`  values.
Because `0 < negative` never become `true`

How to handle this conditions.
Please suggest a solution.

Comment: `array.Max()` is not working for you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ: How to perform .Max() on a property of all objects in a collection and return the object with maximum value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101841/linq-how-to-perform-max-on-a-property-of-all-objects-in-a-collection-and-ret)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to handle this conditions.

You could initialize the max value as the minimum double:

```
var max = double.MinValue;
```

Alternatively you could use the [`.Max()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347632(v=vs.110).aspx) LINQ extension method which will shorten your code, make it more readable and handle the case of an array consisting only of negative values:

```
var max = array.Max();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try like this if you dont want to try any inbuilt functions:

```
int max = arr[0];
foreach (int value in arr) 
{
  if (value > max) 
  max = value;
}
Console.WriteLine(max);
```

**[IDEONE DEMO](https://ideone.com/oXHKpC)**

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [`Max()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.linq.enumerable.max(v=vs.110).aspx) linq extension.

```
var maxvalue = array.Max();
```

Working [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bLymMD)