# Return from list the double value that has the highest absolute value, without making the return value absolute

Tags: c#, math

Short of iterating the collection, is there a way to return the double in a set that has the highest absolute value without making the values in the set actually absolute?

```
double[] vals = new double[] { 2.3, 1.7, -3.8};

vals.Max(v => Math.Abs(v)); // This returns 3.8 instead of -3.8
```

Comment: "iterating the collection". Enumerable.Max iterates a collection. old good `for` loop will be the most performant solution

Comment: @ASh AFAIK native .net iterations have a performance boost over `for` loops, there is a performance concern at play here that I didn't mention and was wondering if there is some sort of native implementation before I went the route of writing my own `IEnumerable` extension.

Comment: What is a `native .net iteration` @Wobbles ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ: How to perform .Max() on a property of all objects in a collection and return the object with maximum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101841/linq-how-to-perform-max-on-a-property-of-all-objects-in-a-collection-and-ret)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One approach to consider:

```
var max = vals
    .OrderByDescending(z => Math.Abs(z))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Alternatively, consider using MoreLinq's [MaxBy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1101979/34092). It is faster than both my and Samvel's solution, especially for larger sets of inputs.

```
var max = vals.MaxBy(z => Math.Abs(z));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways of doing this:

First with `LINQ`:

```
double[] vals = new double[] { 2.3, 1.7, -3.8};
var max = vals.Max(x => Math.Abs(x)); 
Console.WriteLine(vals.Where(z => Math.Abs(z) == max).First());
```

Second with `For` loop:

```
int index =0;
for(int i=0;i<vals.Length;i++)
{
    if(Math.Abs(vals[i])>=Math.Abs(vals[index]))
        index=i;
}
Console.WriteLine(vals[index]);
```

Comment: Ahh some gold-ol linq kung-fu

Comment: Having the `vals.Max` **inside** the `Where` clause will mean the input is iterated over more times than you expect. You will want to move that outside the `Where` clause (but check that `vals.Any()` is true beforehand, otherwise the `Max` will throw an exception).

Comment: @mjwills it is iterating 2 times as in case if you first select all into anonymouse type, also it will not throw exceptions as there is always the element which we consider to be max

Comment: By leaving the `Max` inside the `Where` then it calculates the `Max` for every entry (so basically O(n^2)).

Comment: @mjwills Does your answer suffer the same flaw?

Comment: I don't use `Max`, so no. I am not saying my solution is better or worse, but it lacks that **specific** flaw. You'd have to profile both solutions (using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx over multiple iterations with varying size of inputs) to see which is more performant for your context. If your input size is small, almost any solution will be fast.

Comment: @mjwills I have tried all three(Max in, Max out and your one) versions of code with iterations and Stopwatches and the fastest one is the version with Max out. I will update answer now. Thanks

Comment: @mjwills wow, I have not heard about this LINQ's Extensions Pack. Will save it for future. I think that is the best solution for this answer.