# How to Get the index of the Element which is Maximum in the List <T>

Tags: c#, list, max, indexof

I have a `List` with class name `Product` and I want to know the *index* of the element which has the *maximum value*?

```
class Product
{
    public int ProductNumber { get; set; }
    public int ProductSize { get; set; }
}

List<Product> productList = new List<Product>();

int Index = productList.Indexof(productList.Max(a => a.ProductSize));
```

I have tried this but it is not getting answer! And getting an error:

> "Unable to Cast as Product"

Comment: If perfomance is important, do something like `var indexOfMax = productList.Select((item, index) => new { item, index }).Aggregate((a, b) => a.item.ProductSize > b.item.ProductSize ? a : b).index;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first map each item so that each product is associated with its index, then order by descending and get the first item:

```
int Index = productList
    .Select((x, index) => new { Index = index, Product = x })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Product.ProductSize).First().Index;
```

You don't need another call to `IndexOf`!

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `ArgMax` which is not implemented in *Linq* but can be easily emulated via `Aggregate`:

```
  int Index = productList
    .Select((item, index) => new { item, index })
    .Aggregate((s, v) => v.item.ProductSize > s.item.ProductSize ? v : s)
    .index;
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `Max` will give you the maximum ProductSize, not an instance of Product. This is why you are receiving this error.

You could do it with `OrderByDescending`:

```
var item = productList.OrderByDescending(i => i.ProductSize).First();
int index = productList.IndexOf(item);
```

Comment: Did you mean: `productList.OrderByDescending(i => i.ProductSize).First()`?

Answer (score 0):

This requires a sort

```
var maxObject = productList.OrderByDescending(item => item.ProductSize).First();
var index = productList.IndexOf(maxObject);
```

There are other, easier ways to do this. For example: There is an extension method in [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) that does this.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101841/linq-how-to-perform-max-on-a-property-of-all-objects-in-a-collection-and-ret) question

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `Enumerable.Range`:

```
int index = Enumerable.Range(0, productList.Count)
                      .FirstOrDefault(i => productList[i].ProductSize == productList.Max(x => x.ProductSize));
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/f5RjYk)**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming list is not empty:

```
productList.Indexof(productList.OrderByDescending(a => a.ProductSize).First());
```

Answer (score -1):

productList.Max(a=>a.ProductSize) will return max ProductSize value , not Product object. that condition should be in WHERE condition.