# Unity / Search closes Object from a List by tag

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a Problem to find the closest Object in my List.
There are three types with the tags (Food, Stone and Wood).
I spawn them at the beginning , some for each type, if i found some Resources, they're not hidden anymore, and i add them to the List that a Worker goes to them and harvests them.

So Later in the Game, for expample
i found 3 Stone Resources, then worker should harvest the closest one first everytime....
but i don't know how to iterate throw a Loop only to search for the Tags and how to get the position of the closest one.

Here is some code of the Method that i wrote:

```
void FindNearestFoodRessource()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < gameController.discoveredRessources.Count; i++)
        {
            //float dist = Vector3.Distance(gameController.discoveredRessources[i].transform.position, transform.position);
            GameObject nearestFoodRessource = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Food");

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first - don't use FindGameObject**** in frequently called methods, it is very expensive.

About your problem - just check tag and distance of all the resources:

```
float minDist = Vector3.Distance(gameController.discoveredRessources[0].transform.position, transform.position);
int minDistIndex = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < gameController.discoveredRessources.Count; i++)
{
    if (gameController.discoveredRessources[i].gameObject.CompareTag("Food"))
    {
        float dist = Vector3.Distance(gameController.discoveredRessources[i].transform.position, transform.position);
        if (dist < minDist)
        {
            minDist = dist;
            minDistIndex = i;
        }
    }
}
//Now you can move to gameController.discoveredRessources[minDistIndex]
```

Also you can store all the food/stones/wood in the separate lists when you find it

Answer (score 0):

Using [Linq Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.6) and this usefull extension method [MinBy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31864296/7111561)

```c#
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public static class Linqextensions
{
    public static T MinBy<T, R>(this IEnumerable<T> en, Func<T, R> evaluate) where R : IComparable<R>
    {
        return en.Select(t => new Tuple<T, R>(t, evaluate(t)))
            .Aggregate((max, next) => next.Item2.CompareTo(max.Item2) < 0 ? next : max).Item1;
    }
}
```

(simply copy that code somwhere into your project) you could do it in "one" line

```c#
var closestItem = gameController.discoveredRessources
    // this is a filter only selecting the ones with tag = "Food"
    .Where(obj => obj.CompareTag("Food"))
    // this returns you the item from the list with the lowest distance
    .MinBy(obj => Vector3.Distance(obj.transform.position, transform.position));
```