# Optimize finding Min/Max value using Entity Framework LINQ only

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, big-o

The way I normally find the Min/Max in the database  is using

```
var employeeWithMinSalary = employees.OrderBy(x=>x.Salary).First()
var employeeWithMaxSalary = employees.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Salary).First()
```

However, the performance is O(n * Log(n)).

Is there any other way to Optimize the performance to O(n) using Linq only? (No other libraries)

Comment: List.Max and List.Min.

Comment: There is a decent discussion here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101841/how-to-perform-max-on-a-property-of-all-objects-in-a-collection-and-return-th) which may be beneficial to read.

Comment: @KarenPayne that discussion is for raw linq. I dont think that methodology would be good with EF

Comment: It might be easier to query the max value then grab the record(s) that matches that

Comment: Did you put on index on the `Salary` column? A `select top(1) ...` should be fast on an indexed column.

Comment: @Dirk  Yep.  With an index this operation is O(1).

Comment: And even without an Index, it might be O(n).  For instance on SQL Server you might get a plan with a "TOP N Sort" query operator that finds the top 1 row with a single pass through the table.

Comment: FYI you can combine the queries using an empty `GroupBy` but I am not sure if that will be optimized into one pass for both on the SQL side.

Answer (score -1):

It's not necessary to sort a list to find the Min/Max value from a list. The best sorting algorithm has an average complexity of O(N*logN). Both  Max and Min operations shouldn't take more than O(N), even though the list is unsorted.

You can implement the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914109/how-to-use-linq-to-select-object-with-minimum-or-maximum-property-value) or implementing the following code:

```
   private static Employee MaxBySalary(List<Employee> employees)
    {
        Employee employee = null;
        employees.ForEach(x => employee = ( employee != null && employee.Salary > x.Salary) ? employee : x );
        return employee;
    }

    private static Employee MinBySalary(List<Employee> employees)
    {
        Employee employee = null;
        employees.ForEach(x => employee = (employee != null && employee.Salary < x.Salary) ? employee : x);
        return employee;
    }
```

Both approaches have O(N) complexity

Comment: Can I get the whole entity using MIn/Max?

Comment: @Pavel Do you need the whole record? Your title/question say and imply value

Comment: @DavidDonari Do those work with Entity Framework? If not it is going to dump the entire database into memory to find the value.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23872526)

Comment: @Nick thanks for your suggestions. Please check now

Comment: @DavidDonari it looks much better. I wish I understood the subject matter well enough to judge its technical merit too.