# How to get a tuple with max 2nd element from array of tuples? (C#)

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array of tuples and want to get tuple with a max second element without for cycles. I think it should be some linq statement or something similar:

```
var a = new Tuple<string, int>[n];

// *initializing*

Tuple<string, int> mx = a.Max(t => t.Item2);
```

Also, it must have O(n) complexity

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to perform .Max() on a property of all objects in a collection and return the object with maximum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101841/how-to-perform-max-on-a-property-of-all-objects-in-a-collection-and-return-th) or you can use MoreLINQ's MaxBy function

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I searched for, thank you

Comment: It would have been quicker to just write a for loop than writing a question let alone waiting for an answer to a library that does exactly the same thing

Comment: Well, I was just curious to know, thanks for pointing on an obvious fact:)

Answer (score 0):

If you sort by the ordering constraint, then you can get the first item.

```
    // Populate a Sample
    var a = new Tuple<string, int>[10];
    for(int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        var t = new Tuple<string, int>(i.ToString(), i);
        a[i] = t;
    }
    
    // Get First Item with Highest Value
    Console.WriteLine(a.OrderByDescending(c => c.Item2).First());
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but sorting is slower than search in a common case

Comment: you have an array of 10 elements in your example...so that performance hit is irrelevant

Comment: You are right, okay, I clarified it